# Selenium WebDriver w/Java: How to wait for specific element to be visible located by multiple By objects?

Tags: java, ajax, selenium

I write selenium tests for an AJAX application, and to make it run stable I use explicit waits. This works correctly if I use a single by to locate my element, like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 50);
wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.ignoring(InvalidElementStateException.class);

By by = By.cssSelector("button");

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
getDriver().findElement(by).click();
```

However I want to wait for an element to be clickable, that is located by multiple bys, like this:

```
WebElement element = getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("form")).findElement(By.cssSelector("button"));
ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element);
```

The first line, where the element is found, is prone to race conditions, and does not work like if it was located with a single By. I considered concatenating the By objects in a single By, however i use both XPath and CSS selectors to locate my elements, so this is not an option. XPath is used, as I match on containing text, which is not supported by CSS3.

Is it possible to replicate the behavior of the first example, while still being able to locate the elements using multiple By objects?

Answer (score 1):

You are using CSS Selectors, you shouldn't need to use multiple findElement().

You can do that all in the same selector. You *should* be able to do everything you can do with XPath using CSS Selectors.

I.E.

```
 getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("form button"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. I match on containing text, and as of the CSS3 specification, it is not possible to select based on that.

Comment: This seems like an important detail that is missing from the question. Please edit the question and add this and any other relevant info.

Comment: I added the information to the question. If you feel like other relevant information is missing, please let me know.